# Sublimelinter cpplint does not recognize ipp files

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, cpplint

I am trying to setup sublime text 3 to work on C++ development.

I installed cpplint and followed the installation instructions. While the documentation indicates that cpplint will lint any file with syntax set to "C++", this is not the case for me. cpplint only works when my file has an extention "cpp" or "hpp". The moment I change the file name extension from "hpp" to "ipp" the linter stops working.

Does anybody know what configuration I need to make?

Comment: "View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as ... > C++"

Comment: "View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as > C++"

Comment: Was first thing I tried, but for some reason it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out cpplint source code has a check to ignore extensions that aren't the usual ones in function

```
GetAllExtensions()
```

Simply adding "ipp" to the list and building cpplint solves the issue.